# Java EE web application - Tomcat 7 server hangs unnecessarily

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, tomcat7

I am using Tomcat 7 web server to host/deploy my web app. The app is running fine without any issues. But only some times (means having probability of 1% only), the server hangs up without any reason. I have allocated it enough memory to JVM/Tomcat. Also I can't see any logs since app is not able to write log file because of it doesn't respond.
I have checked the max no of connections to DB and they are also not exceeding the limit.

How can I find the cause for this ? 
I need to restart server to resolve this...
Please help.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take three thread dumps approximately 10s apart and then compare the contents of those thread dumps to determine which thread(s) is(are) not moving. Once you know which threads are problem, then you need to figure out why they are not moving.